# Google static map rendering to wrong location

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to render a hotel, Hilton Paris Orly Airport, but google is showing me a location somewhere in London.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=680x200&zoom=14&markers=color:red%7cHilton+Orly+Sud+267+Paris+FR+94544&center=Hilton+Orly+Sud+267+Paris+FR+94544&style=feature:all|element:all&key=AIzaSyBYXQVdTSIE6PrSvHmuOBlheFrMUUEkdO0

How can I fix it? Or how can google fix it?

Thanks for the advice.
G

Answer (score 0):

Google calls that the ["Hilton Paris Orly Airport Hotel"](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Hilton+Paris+Orly+Airport+Hotel/@48.7311395,2.3629693,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x47e675d237193f8b:0x56b8b9535ccdb7a4?hl=en)

It address is "Rue Clément Ader, 94390 Paray-Vieille-Poste, France"

Use the [address](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=680x200&zoom=14&markers=color:red%7cRue%20Cl%C3%A9ment%20Ader,%2094390%20Paray-Vieille-Poste,%20France&center=Rue%20Cl%C3%A9ment%20Ader,%2094390%20Paray-Vieille-Poste,%20France&style=feature:all|element:all)

[image: Static Map of Orly Airport Hotel]